# fmt::print(fg(fmt::color::blue), "Test") doesn't print colored text

Tags: c++, fmt

OS: ubuntu 22.04

output of "echo $TERM": xterm-256color

fmt version: 10.2.1

The following code can print colored text:

```cpp
std::cout << "\033[1;31mbold red text\033[0m" << std::endl
```

Answer (score 0):

`fmt::color` requires [RGB color support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit) which is not available on some terminals. You can use `fmt::terminal_color` instead which is more widely supported:

```cpp
#include <fmt/color.h>

int main() {
  fmt::print(fg(fmt::terminal_color::blue), "Test");
}
```

Godbolt: https://www.godbolt.org/z/e1qj5K8Ys.